# How can I zip in a Wordpress Plugin and ensure it will work if the target system doesnt have the ZipArchive module installed

Tags: php, wordpress, zip

When developing my plugin I was using ZipArchive to unzip a file, however it appears that on some wordpress hosting providers (e.g. GoDaddy) the user actually has to manually install this ZipArchive module seperately.

Is there an alternative way I can zip a file in my plugin, without forcing the user to install modules via c-panel?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199679/discussion-between-treybake-and-max-carroll).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempting to install or enable ZipArchive on the user's server is a security flaw.

We cannot guarantee that ZipArchive will be utilizable on any particular environment and there's no way to include this dependency in your project.

There is a [package called `nelexa\zip`](https://github.com/Ne-Lexa/php-zip/) on packigist that is not dependent on ZipArchive. `PhpZip`'s only dependency is PHP 5.5 or greater.

Installing it is simple using `composer`:

`composer require nelexa/zip`

Then, it is just a matter of modifying a few lines of code to work with the new library, instead of `ZipArchive`.

```
-        $zip = new \ZipArchive;
-        $res = $zip->open($zipFilePath);
-        $zip->extractTo($extractionPath . '/');
-        $zip->close();
-  
+        $zip = new \PhpZip\ZipFile();
+
+        $zip->openFile($zipFilePath)
+            ->extractTo($extractionPath);
+
```